# PHP Assoc Array custom usort function

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I sort the keys in descending order by their value and if two keys have the same quantity, I must print them in alphabetical order. I know that probably a user function must be created, but i was not able to learn how to make those.

Array:

```
array(3) {
  ["motes"]=>
  int(3)
  ["shards"]=>
  int(5)
  ["fragments"]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Output:

```
fragments: 5
shards: 5
motes: 3
```

Comment: Please provide input / output data as php variables with its contents.

Comment: Hello, the input is a single line that i use explode to separate. I have a slight error thou, the fragments are 5 not 255. Editing right away.

Comment: Could you also put the code that makes the unsorted array from the single line in your question?

Comment: So the words are the keys and the numbers are the values?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Without more information (like the actual code), any answer or suggestion would simply be wild guesses.

Comment: Alright guys, thank you for welcoming me and sorry for the inconvenience. Lets skip the input and say that the array we have is this. I must sort it by the key's value in descending order and then if two keys have the same value, I must print them in alphabetical order. I did not paste the full code, since its a lot.

Comment: So, write a function that compares two array items by those specified criteria, and returns the appropriate value. A pretty extensive explanation of how that works you can find under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a user defined function with [`uksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) to achieve what you want. By also passing the array to the function, we can cheat and sort on the values before sorting on the keys:

```
$array = array('motes' => 3, 'shards' => 5, 'fragments' => 5);
uksort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($array) { 
    if ($array[$a] < $array[$b]) return 1;
    elseif ($array[$a] > $array[$b]) return -1; 
    else return strcmp($a, $b); });
print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array ( 
    [fragments] => 5
    [shards] => 5
    [motes] => 3 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/RTRV1)